# What is the modrewrite rule to flatten access to awstats

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, awstats

My current url to access my awstats is

```
http://my.server.com/awstats/awstats.pl?config=foo
```

I would like to use apache and mod_rewrite to

```
http://my.server.com/foo
```

My attempt is

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) /awstats/awstats.pl?config=$1 [NC]
```

but I just get a 404.

The error.log doesn't give me much help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a $ after so that the entire string is eaten by the regexp, and then use [L] so the rewrite engine knows to stop processing and apply the rule.

Remember to switch on the rewrite engine and set the rewrite base.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /awstats/awstats.pl?config=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I added the $ and the L flag so now my rule is RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /awstats.pl?config=$1 [NC,L] but now I am getting the awstats.pl file as a plain text file instead of being processed by perl.

Comment: @jsmorris Does it work (ie. run the Perl script properly) when you go to the URL directly?

Comment: if I remove the rewrite rule and use the longer url, it works fine.

Comment: @jsmorris Try adding `T=application/x-httpd-cgi` to the options list along with `NC,L` == `[NC,L,T=application/x-httpd-cgi]` - if you are using mod_perl that MIME type might need to be different.